# Group, normality, subgroup question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $N,H$ be subgroups of $G$ with $N$ normal. Show that $$HN = \{hn \mid h \in H, n \in N \}$$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check that it satisfies the subgroup axioms.  Is $1$ in $HN$?  If $a,b \in HN$, is $a b^{-1} \in HN$?.  Remember by saying that $a,b \in HN$, you are saying $a = h_1 n_1$ and $b = h_2 n_2$.  Let me know if you are still stuck after thinking about this for a while and if so, I'll give a more detailed hint.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a=hn$ and $b=km$ for $h,k\in H$ and $n,m\in N$ and check whether $ab^{-1}\in HN$. $$(hn)(km)^{-1}=hnm^{-1}k^{-1}=\underbrace{\left(hk^{-1}\right)}_{\in H}\,\,\,\,k\,\,\underbrace{\left(nm^{-1}\right)}_{\in N}\,k^{-1}=\underbrace{\left(hk^{-1}\right)}_{\in H}\,\underbrace{\left(knm^{-1}k^{-1}
\right)}_{\in N}$$
Note that the last step holds *if and only if* $N$ is normal.  Thus by the one-step subgroup test, $HN$ is a subgroup if and only if $K$ normalizes $N$.

Answer (score 0):

### **Hint:**

1. For $H,N\leq G, HN\leq G\iff HN=NH;$
2. $N\triangleleft G\implies gN=Ng~\forall~g\in G$ and so in particular $\forall~g\in H.$